# Angular Export Alias

Tags: angular, typescript

I am creating a module, and for some reason it is aliasing the type exports.  I have searched around and cannot find the answer.  The module looks something like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common'
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { PhoneMaskDirective } from './directives/phone-mask.directive';
import { ZipCodeMaskDirective } from './directives/zip-code-mask.directive';

import { DateFormatPipe } from './pipes/date-format.pipe';
import { PhonePipe } from './pipes/phone.pipe';
import { ZipCodePipe } from './pipes/zipcode.pipe';

import { AddressComponent } from './address/address.component';
import { EmailComponent } from './email/email.component';
import { PhoneComponent } from './phone/phone.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
      DateFormatPipe,
      PhonePipe,
      ZipCodePipe,
      PhoneMaskDirective,
      ZipCodeMaskDirective,
      AddressComponent,
      EmailComponent,
      PhoneComponent
  ],
  exports: [
      DateFormatPipe,
      PhonePipe,
      ZipCodePipe,
      PhoneMaskDirective,
      ZipCodeMaskDirective,
      AddressComponent,
      EmailComponent,
      PhoneComponent
    ]
})
export class MyModule { }
export * from './address/address-validation-messages';
export * from './address/address-view-properties';
export * from './email/email-validation-messages';
export * from './email/email-view-properties';
export * from './phone/phone-validation-messages';
export * from './phone/phone-view-properties';
```

what comes out the other end looks something like this:

```
/**
 * Generated bundle index. Do not edit.
 */
export * from './index';
export { AddressComponent as ɵk } from './address/address.component';
export { PhoneMaskDirective as ɵh } from './directives/phone-mask.directive';
export { ZipCodeMaskDirective as ɵj } from './directives/zip-code-mask.directive';
export { EmailComponent as ɵl } from './email/email.component';
export { PhoneComponent as ɵm } from './phone/phone.component';
export { DateFormatPipe as ɵc } from './pipes/date-format.pipe';
export { PhonePipe as ɵd } from './pipes/phone.pipe';
export { ZipCodePipe as ɵg } from './pipes/zipcode.pipe';
```

Why are the types getting aliased?

Comment: are other parts of the generated code using the aliases?  seems like it could be a minification technique

Comment: I think when the minified files are generated, to shorten the names, they are being aliased.